# retrieving data from firestore collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have my firebase collection set up like this:

```
customers
uid
subscriptions
subscriptions uid
items
    plan: true or false
```

I need to access this plan variable to check if the plan is active or inactive??? I can attach a photo of the config in firestore if necessary? but here's the code that I currently use to data from firestore. would I be able to use this still but change it up accordingly?

```
 firestore 
.collection("profiledata") 
.doc(userID) 
.get() 
.then((doc) => { 
setProfileData(doc.data()); 
});
```

here's the photos to show the config
[image]
here's the second photo
[image]

in the second photo -- the plan section has a 'row' that says active or inactive... I need to grab that!

Comment: It seems like you already know how to fetch the data. So what is the problem with accessing it?

Comment: @trixn the profiledata collection is set up much less complex then the one I posted above. it is simply one collection and one document. this one above is 2 collections and 2 documents. just wondering how to retrieve that plan object value

Comment: Please double check your question, especially the first part that describes your collections. It's not clear how your collections and their relations look like. Why is there a line `subscriptions` and `subscriptions uid`? Should that mean that `customers` is a collection that has another collection `subscriptions` that has a field `plan`? How is anybody supposed to understand this? Why is `plan: true or false` indented and the other parts not?

Comment: ive edited my question to try to make more clear

Comment: So in other words you want to get the `subscription` documents (that contain `items` with each having a `plan`) given a certain customer id?

Comment: yes exactly right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230895/discussion-between-gianluca-and-trixn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all subscriptions (with the items) of a user it should be:

```
firebase.collection('customers').doc(userID).collection('subscriptions').get()
  .then(subscriptions => {
    subscriptions.forEach(subscription => {
      // subscription.data() should give you a subscription with its items
      console.log(subscription.data());
    });
  })
```

This would be how you query, if a subscription exists, that has the `status` `'active'` for a given customer:

```
firebase.collection('customers').doc(userID).collection('subscriptions')
  .where('status', '==', 'active').get()
  .then(activeSubscriptions => {
    // if this is true, the user has no active subscription.
    console.log(activeSubscriptions.empty)
  });
```

Getting the `status` of the subscription:

```
firebase.collection('customers').doc(userID).collection('subscriptions').get()
    .then(subscriptions => {
        if (subscriptions.empty) {
            console.log('User has no subscriptions')
        } else if (subscriptions.size > 1) {
            console.log('ERROR: User has multiple subscriptions')
        } else {
            subscriptions.forEach(theSubscription => {
                // there is only this subscription
                const data = theSubscription.data();
                console.log(data.status);
            });
        }
    });
```